# Does a continuous function attain its extremes on the closure of an open bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $u\in C(\bar{U})$. According to the Heine-Borel theorem, being compact is equivalent to being closed and bounded. Can we then conclude that the closure $\bar{U}$ is compact and that $u$ attains its extremes on $\bar{U}$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $U$ is bounded, it's closure $\overline{U}$ is bounded as well. Indeed, this is easily seen to be the case because an element of $\overline{U}$ is the limit of elements in $U$, all of which are bounded. Also, $\overline{U}$ and trivially a closed set. Thus by Heine-Borel $\overline{U}$ is a compact set. Now, $u$ is a real-valued continuous function on a compact set and by the extreme value theorem $u$ attains both its minimum and maximum, i.e. there are $m , M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$m= \min\{u(x): x \in \overline{U}\}$$
$$M= \max\{u(x): x \in \overline{U}\}$$